# Xcode 9 fails to build Swift 4 project with pod

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, alamofire, code-signing

When attempting to build my Swift 4 project in Xcode 9 beta 2, some code signing error occurs after which the build of my app is discontinued.

The error that is shown in Xcode:

```
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign -  --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements '/Users/nickgaens/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Emprova_Swift-bbvmoytlhlbqpueyftstselvwhdj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Emprova GPS Swift.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework'
/Users/nickgaens/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Emprova_Swift-bbvmoytlhlbqpueyftstselvwhdj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Emprova GPS Swift.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework: No such file or directory
```

[image: Screenshot of Xcode error]

As you might notice, the `--sign` argument is followed by a single `-` character.

My setup:

- Xcode 9 beta 2 (9M137d) with its bundled Swift 4-version
- Cocoapods v1.2.1 with Podfile

```
platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'Emprova GPS Demo Swift' do
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.5.0'
  pod 'AlamofireNetworkActivityIndicator', '~> 2.2.0'
  pod 'KeyClip'
  pod 'Localize-Swift', '~> 1.7.1'
  pod 'FMDB'

end

target 'Emprova GPS Swift' do
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.5.0'
  pod 'AlamofireNetworkActivityIndicator', '~> 2.2.0'
  pod 'KeyClip'
  pod 'Localize-Swift', '~> 1.7.1'
  pod 'FMDB'

end
```

- I didn't change a single letter of any of the added pods files.
- I opened `Pods.xcodeproj` to check and double check `Build Settings` -  `Code Signing Identitiy` of the Alamofire pod/target, but it is set to `Don't Code Sign`.
- I already checked my Keychain Access app to see if the `Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority` wasn't expired (it isn't) and is marked as trusted (it is).
- I already emptied the DerivedData directory multiple times (`~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`) and performed a `Clean` (both via `Cmd+K` and `Cmd+Alt+Shift+K` to no avail.
- I already attempted to set the Xcode 'Command Line Tools' (`Preferences` - `Locations` - `Command Line Tools`) to both `Xcode 8.3.3 (8E3004b)` and `Xcode 9.0 (9M137d)` to no avail.

Completely ran out of ideas after having spent multiple hours searching for a solution. Does anyone have a clue why Xcode 9 no longer builds my project?

Also, link to my issue on Alamofires GitHub page, for the sake of completeness: [#2183](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/2183).

Comment: Could you check which `SWIFT_VERSION` the `Alamofire` pod is using (See Build Settings for that). You could also try `pod 'Alamofire', :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git', :branch => 'swift4'`

Comment: `SWIFT_VERSION` of the `Alamofire` pod is set to `Swift 3.2`. Will attempt your 'swift 4' branch proposal now.

Comment: I edited the Podfile so the Alamofire pod points to the 'swift4' branch, but that doesn't change a thing. Xcode still outputs the same error.

Comment: I tried to remove and reinstall ruby with cocoapods. Try to install several differrent versions of cocoapods, from brew and from gem. Nothing! The solution which helps me as a result, it's just to set up a check in the `Signin` section in Pods project, main settings, named `Automatically manage signin` and choose my work team profile. That's all. Maybe, this solution can helps someone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out what's wrong! Xcode continued using the `.xcodeproj` file to open my project when selecting it on the welcome screen, but `Cocoapods` requires the `.xcworkspace` file to be used! There's a visual distinction between both entries on Xcode's Welcome screen afterwards: [difference between Xcode workspace and project on Welcome screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyfpH.png).

Opening the workspace shows two projects in Xcode's `Project Navigator`: one for my app and a second one named `Pods`, which embodies all installed pods. Building the app no longer shows weird build errors.