# Do I need to explicitly state which version of alamofire I want to install using cocoapods in xcode 9, swift 4

Tags: swift, cocoapods, alamofire, xcode9

There is this tutorial re: alamofire https://www.raywenderlich.com/147086/alamofire-tutorial-getting-started-2

And in it the pod to install is declared as 'Alamofire', '~> 4.2.0'

Do I need to specify the version 4.2.0 or can i just declare it as pod 'Alamofire'?

I went to the Alamfoire page on cocoapods and i couldn't actually find what the latest stable version is although i'm sure it's there somewhere.

And there is this post re: alamofire not working with xcode 9/swift 4 [Xcode 9 fails to build Swift 4 project with Alamofire pod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44780972/xcode-9-fails-to-build-swift-4-project-with-alamofire-pod) but i think the issue was the person opened the wrong project and not with the code base.

But if anyone knows of any other issues feel free to shout out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you declare the following you will get the latest stable version:

```
pod 'Alamofire'
```

If you declare a version number you then you'll that version:

```
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.2.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Explanation for version.

```
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.2.0'


'> 0.1' Any version higher than 0.1
'>= 0.1' Version 0.1 and any higher version
'< 0.1' Any version lower than 0.1
'<= 0.1' Version 0.1 and any lower version
```